# What visual control used in the Here Maps for WP8, for sliding map and bottom panel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, here-api

I wanna make visual control for sliding between map and bottom panel like in the Here Maps for WP8. How is it made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is custom made and it shouldn't be complicated to make one yourself. It consists of a panel that is higher than the screen and has a draggable upper part. You can track Manipulation* events on it and when user starts dragging upwards, you can use `RenderTransforms` to move the entire control up and down.

For smoother effect use animations to slide the upper/lower part into its place. You can easily construct such animations in code and apply them on the fly.